# $Ax(t)=a(t)x(t)$ a non compact operator because $AA^{-1}=A^{-1}A=I$?

Tags: functional-analysis

> **Example of non-compact operator**:
> $X=C_{[0,1]}$
> $Ax(t)=a(t)x(t)\:\:\:a(t)\neq 0$ so the operator is not compact.
>
> $|x(t)|>0$, if $t\in(\alpha,\beta)\subset[0,1]$
>
> $x(t)=\frac{y(t)}{a(t)}=A^{-1}y$, then $AA^{-1}=A^{-1}A=I$ so A is not compact.

**Question:**

What argument does the author uses to conclude that $A$ is not compact when the author states $AA^{-1}=A^{-1}A=I$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you know the following?  1. The composition of a compact and a bounded operator is compact. 2. The identity operator on a Banach space is compact if and only if the Banach space is finite-dimensional. 3. $C([0,1])$ is infinite-dimensional.

Comment: @user539887 Thanks! After your comment I looked for those points and I am trying to figure out the problem.